# Habilitar input quando chegar na quantidade de checkbox selecionada

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Pessoal tenho esse `input`:

```
<input type="submit" id="cadastrar" value="Cadastrar" disabled>
```

Tenho um grid que é preenchido e cada linha tem um `checkbox`:

```
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="seleciona" name="seleciona[]" value= <=$row_questao['codprova'] ?>" />
</td>
```

Tenho esse script que ao clicar apenas no 1º `checkbox` do Grid ele habilita e desabilita, do 2º em diante ele não funciona:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#seleciona").on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $("#cadastrar").prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $("#cadastrar").prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });
});
```

Preciso que ele fique `enabled` quando uma quantidade x 'vai vir de uma consulta mysql' de `checkbox` for selecionada e quando desmarcar 1 do total ela volte para `disabled`.

Comment: oi, tente complementar seu código o mais possível do resultado, com o restante do html para realizar um teste, se possível disponibilize seu código dentro do snippet no editor de pergunta.

Comment: olá, o resto para complementar seria html sem importância.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está repetindo o `id="seleciona"`, e com isso o JavaScript irá sempre buscar o primeiro que achar. Por isso o change só funciona no primeiro checkbox.

Um id deve ser único na página, não pode ser repetido.

Se você quer habilitar o input somente quando um número mínimo determinado forem marcados, basta comparar esse número com a quantidade que foi marcada. Se a quantidade marcada for igual ou maior que o mínimo, habilita o input, se for menor, desabilita.

O número mínimo a ser marcado você pode colocar num atributo `data-*` no input #cadastrar:

```
<input type="submit" data-min="2" id="cadastrar" value="Cadastrar" disabled>
                         ↑
```

Para fazer isso nem precisa de id's, basta selecionar os elementos pelo `name`, já que todos possuem o mesmo:

```js
$(function(){

   $(":checkbox[name='seleciona[]']").on("change", function(){
      // pega o valor mínimo
      var minimo = $("#cadastrar").data("min");
      // conta quantos foram marcados
      var marcados = $(":checkbox[name='seleciona[]']:checked").length;
      
      $("#cadastrar").prop("disabled", marcados >= minimo ? false : true );
      
   });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" data-min="2" id="cadastrar" value="Cadastrar" disabled>
<br>
Marque pelo menos 2 checkbox para habilitar o campo acima:
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="seleciona[]" value="a" />
<input type="checkbox" name="seleciona[]" value="b" />
<input type="checkbox" name="seleciona[]" value="c" />
```

Comment: Perfeito @Sam, era exatamente o que queria, mas surgiu outra dúvida como levaria o total de checks a ser marcado vindo de um select no mysql?

Comment: Como assim? Não entendi.

Comment: O total de check's a ser marcado não vai ser o total que está na tela, no seu ex: 3, vão ser uns 30 a 50 checks no grid, dai vou ter um select que vai retornar um valor e esse valor é quantidade a ser marcada para habilitar o input. ao invés de ser `var total = $(":checkbox[name='seleciona[]']").length;`, teria que ser algo assim: `var total = $variavel['quatidade']`;

Comment: Alterei a resposta. Veja se era isso.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, show de bola, vlw.